# How to compare number of rows with no of column with value in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to know if we can compare no.of row count and a column with value

Example:

```
id    flag1   flag2   flag3
------------------------------
1      Y       Y       Y
------------------------------
2      N       Y       Y
------------------------------
3      Y       Y       N
------------------------------
```

`count(*) = 3` and if `count(column) with 'Y'` matches with `count(*)` then it should return `true`.

Result:

```
---------
True
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear.  One interpretation is that you want to know if all the values in a column are "Y".  You can do this with aggregation and a `case`:

```
select (case when min(flag1) = max(flag1) and min(flag1) = 'Y' then 'True' else 'False' end) as flag1_ally,
       (case when min(flag2) = max(flag2) and min(flag2) = 'Y' then 'True' else 'False' end) as flag2_ally,
       . . .
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  case when count(*) = count(nullif(flag1,'N')) then 'True' else 'False' end as f1
       ,case when count(*) = count(nullif(flag2,'N')) then 'True' else 'False' end as f2
       ,case when count(*) = count(nullif(flag3,'N')) then 'True' else 'False' end as f3

from    t 
;
```